# Help finding mistake in this problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When I am doing math during free time, I produce a strange result when doing this:
$$(x^{\frac{1}{2}})^{2}=x+1$$ (definitely no solution) 
$$x^{\frac {1}{2}}=(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$1=\frac{(x+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}}$$
$$1=\frac{x^{2}+2x+1}{x^{2}}$$
$$x^{2}=x^{2}+2x+1$$
$$2x+1=0$$
$$x=-0.5$$
Can you help find my mistake in this situation?Thanks.

Comment: At some point you raised both sides to the fourth power.  That picked up extra "solutions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you went from the third line to the fourth, you took the 4th power of both sides. (I'm not sure why -- you could have just squared both).

But $x^4 = y^4$ does not imply that $x = y$. (for instance $(-1)^4 = 1^4$, but $-1$ and $1$ are different.

So in taking 4th powers, you may have introduced new solutions that are not real solutions of the original equation.

**Post-comment addition**

To see why taking a 4th power introduces new solutions, let's look at the squaring function, $f(x) = x^2$, defined on the real numbers.

The function $f$ is *not* injective, i.e., there can be two different numbers $a$ and $b$ with $f(a) = f(b)$. For instance, $a = 2$ and $b = -2$ both have the property that $f(a) = f(b) = 4$.

If I tell you that I'm thinking of numbers $x$ and $y$ with $f(x) = f(y)$, can you conclude that $x = y$? No!

Why not? Well, suppose that $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are both equal to $4$. Then $x$ could be $2$ and $y$ could be $-2$, and those are different.

Now let's go the other direction. Suppose I tell you that 
$$
x = y = 2
$$
Then we can apply $f$ to get that 
$$
x^2 = y^2 = 4.
$$

But that doesn't mean that every solution to the SECOND equation is a solution to the first one. For instance, $x = 2, y = -2$ is a solution to the second equation, but not a solution to the first.

The general principle to derive from this example is that if you have an equation, and apply a function $f$ to both sides to get a new equation, every solution of the original equation is still a solution of the new equation (provided that they are all within the domain of $f$). But *not* every solution to the new equation is a solution to the original. If you want to guarantee that a well, then the function $f$ must have an *inverse*, i.e., a function $g$ with $g(f(x)) = x$ and $f(g(x)) = x$ for every $x$.

Examples:

$f(x) = x + 1$; $g(x) = x - 1$. This example shows that you can "add 1 to both sides of an equation" without changing the set of solutions.

$f(x) = 2x$; $g(x) = x/2$. This example shows that you can "multiply both sides of an equation by 2" without changing the set of solutions.

But since $f(x) = x^2$ does not have an inverse function, you cannot ensure that squaring both sides of an equation leaves the solution set unchanged.

Comment: But isn't that the first line had shown that already no solution, so taking square means that this will form a solution? I take the 4th power as taking power of cube will return to first equation$x=x+1$

Comment: See post-comment addition.

Comment: So increase the power by 1 of the equation increase extra solution by one and decreasing power of solution has no effect, right?

Comment: No...it's rather more complicated than that, which is why I wrote that long explanation. But if you want a quick rule: raising both sides to an *even* power may introduce spurious solutions; raising both sides to an *odd* power will not. That's because odd-power functions, like $x \mapsto x^3$, have inverses, and even-power functions do not.

Comment: I rise the equation to the 5th power, although it has no real solution, but still exists two extra  complex solution, is the complex solution not counted as solutions?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto x^5$, defined on the reals, has an inverse; the corresponding function defined on the complex number field, does not. So if you're looking for real solution then, no, the complex solutions are not counted as solutions. Think of $x^2 + 1 = 0$. That has two complex solutions ... but it also has a single solution in the field with two elements. But we don't count that one, do we? Nor do we count the infinitely many quaternion solutions, or octonian solutions. That's why we specify the domain in which we're working when we ask for solutions to equations.

Comment: But even I count the complex solution as a solution, it doesn't plug into the original equation. (Is there are any complex solution for $x=x+1$?)

Comment: No -- there is no solution for this in any field, because in every field, the number $1$ is different from $0$ (that's one of the field axioms).

Comment: So, even I accept complex solution, the complex solutions I obtain by raising to odd number power is extra?

Comment: The MAY be extra, yes -- because odd powers (except 1) are not invertible over the complexes.

Comment: "So increase the power by 1 of the equation increase extra solution by one and decreasing power of solution has no effect, right?"This is still right including complex solutions, isn't?As the power of the equation reach 3,the extra solution increase from 1 to 2(including complex solution)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of all these intermediate steps to create the "paradox".

$$x=x+1\implies x^2=x^2+2x+1\implies2x+1=0.$$

Actually the squaring step is invalid, as it introduces the extra solution

$$-x=x+1.$$

---

When you use a squaring, like $a=b\implies a^2=b^2$, you must remember that $-a=b$ is ruled out.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is a beginner's mistake.

Comment: I admit it.... I am a beginner....

Answer (score 0):

But the domain gives $x>0$.

Which says that our equation has no solutions.

We can see this immediately:
$$\left(x^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2=x+1$$ it's
$$x=x+1$$ or
$$0=1,$$ which has no solutions.

Comment: So I am here to ask why I get the result above, I already know from the beginning there is no solution.

Comment: @lyk You have no mistakes in your computations. You need to write the domain before. You got $x=-0.5$, but the domain says: $x>0$. Thus, your equation has no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have the intermediate step $$1=\frac {x^{\frac 12}}{(x+1)^{\frac 12}}$$

Now that doesn't have a solution, and when you square it you get $$1=\frac {x}{x+1}$$ which again has no solution. However $$-1=\frac {x}{x+1}$$ has the solution $x=-\frac 12$, and these two equations combine into one when you square either.

In general if you have $x=y$ and square it to get $x^2=y^2$, the second equation can be rewritten $(x+y)(x-y)=0$ or $x=\pm y$. So the squared equation has a solution which does not belong to the original equation.